# Is it possible to change the base url in mod_pagespeed to use https

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed

We are using Google PageSpeed module running on Apache, it is possible to configure it so that the base url uses https?

It currently outputs the following.

```
<noscript>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;url='http://example.com/?ModPagespeed=noscript'" />
    <style><!--table,div,span,font,p{display:none} --></style>
    <div style="display:block">Please click <a href="http://example.com/?ModPagespeed=noscript">here</a> if you are not redirected within a few seconds.</div>
</noscript>
```

It should be https://example.com - It there a setting inpagespeed.conf to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the site was running behind a load balancer. All HTTPS requests were forwarded via HTTP. To correct the issue we needed to set

```
ModPagespeedRespectXForwardedProto on
```

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/https_support) for https support explains the process.

Comment: This worked! (used the nginx version from the documentation link) `pagespeed RespectXForwardedProto on;`